# On Windows 10 android SDK- Changing in index.android.js but app not refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

#### First Issue when react-native start error is coming

(node:4380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Watcher took too long to load (NodeWatcher)

#### Second issue

When I am changing in index.android.js file and save it.App is not refreshing.

React Native version is - 0.33
Npm version - 3.10.3
node version - 6.6.0
OS - Windows 10

On First Time app is working fine but when i doing changing in file and doing save app is not refreshing
Please help me out.......

Comment: Same issue, I can't even start react-native packager because of promise rejection error, I'm using Windows 10 too. I had the Android SDK already installed (before react-native I mean), I don't know if it is important.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it went away after I reinstalled react-native and react.
The issue is watchman isn't working properly so increasing MAX_WAIT TIME to 360000 could help in this file inside the project (node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/FileWatcher/index.js)

Comment: While this may have worked in your situation, I don't think across the board this would be a valid solution. You ideally don't want to perform manual changes inside the node_module files.